# Verb tense agreement - 'Do' vs. 'did'

Tags: verbs, tenses, agreement

I want to say something like, 'Would many women, if asked, say they feel unsatisfied with the way they are treated? They would say that they /do/.'

A friend advised me to change 'do' to 'did'. But I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**did** is the past tense of **do**.

If you say "They would say that they **do**" then this is the present tense which matches "feel" in the question and implies that the dissatisfaction is ongoing.

If you say "They would say that they **did**" then this is the past tense which does not match and it implies that they were dissatisfied in the past, which is in conflict with "... are treated". They cannot be dissatisfied in the past with something that is happening now.

So I suggest that you are right and your friend is wrong.

However it is very common to hear **did** in spoken English even though it it not strictly grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "do" is the correct word to use.

Depending on context, either "did" or "are" is a better option.

If you're asking about a general feeling, use "are".

> Would women say they feel unsatisfied?  They would say that they **are** [unsatisfied].

If context means you're asking about how they felt about a specific interaction, then you would say...

> Would many women say they **felt** unsatisfied with the customer service?  They would say that they **did** [feel unsatisfied].

As pointed out below, it could also be:

> Would many women say they **feel** unsatisfied with the customer service?  They would say that they **do** [feel unsatisfied].

Frankly, I'd reorganize the sentence entirely to avoid the clunky phrasing by taking out "feel":

> If asked, would many women say they are unsatisfied with the way they are treated?
>
> Yes, they would.

Comment: You are parsing it incorrectly (or incompletely). It's *They would say that they **do** [feel unsatisfied].* Neither version is wrong. (Personally, I find *do* to be more natural. I don't like *are* here. I acknowledge that it's grammatical, but it feels like an awkward mixing of syntactic terms.)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with what you say.  I think it is just an awkwardly worded question and answer and would restructure it to avoid it entirely.

Comment: @JasonBassford I edited my answer to address what you brought up.  Weigh in, if you'd like.